# add 1 to number within <h3> tag

Tags: jquery, html, numbers

I have multiple (how many is not known because it can change) `<h3>` tags with the same class .love_nummer

```
<h3 class="love_nummer">1</h3>
```

Inside these tags is a number, with every .love_nummer goes a other  tag with the class .give_love

```
<h3 class="give_love">LOVE</h3>
```

Now I want when you click on the .give_love only the number within the `<h3>` tag (.love_nummer) within the same `<div>` as .give_love becomes one number higher. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
$('.give_love').on("click", function(e){
      var love_givin = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.love_nummer').val());
      love_givin++;
    });
```

Comment: could you please share complete HTML structure. Like what will be the parent of these 2 tags and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed you have used `.val()` to get the text, which can't be used. Instead you should use `.text()`.

You need to replace to this:

```js
$('.give_love').on("click", function(e) {
  var love_givin = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.love_nummer').text());
  $(this).parent().find('.love_nummer').text(++love_givin);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="love_nummer">1</h3>

<h3 class="give_love">LOVE</h3>
```

Comment: by this way all `love_nummer` will get modified and not only the associated one.

Comment: yeah i know i already deleted that comment, was to quick reacting

Comment: @TimoVossen same here, just updated the comment too. :D

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is for elements which have a *value* property, `h3` is not such an element.
Try `text()` instead and don't forget to update it afterwards:

```js
$('.give_love').on("click", function(e) {
  var element = $(this).parent().find('.love_nummer');
  var love_givin = parseInt(element.text());
  love_givin++;
  element.html(love_givin.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="love_nummer">1</h3>
<h3 class="give_love">LOVE</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will only increase number of just previous text

```js
$('.give_love').on("click", function(e) {
var love_num=$(this).prev('.love_nummer');  
var love_givin = parseInt(love_num.text());
  love_num.text(++love_givin);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="love_nummer">1</h3>

<h3 class="give_love">LOVE</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it just looks like you didn't do anything to update the value after you calculated it.  Also since you're working with `<h>` tags better to use `.text()` than `.val()` in my opinion.

```
$('.give_love').click(function(e) {
  var love_givin = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.love_nummer').text());
  love_givin++;
  $(this).parent().find('.love_nummer').text(love_givin);
});
```

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/v35f6mpw/2/